# How to check if a texture is bound in OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

In OpenGL ES, is there a way to check if a texture is currently bound, as to avoid the overhead of state changes in `glBindTexture()`? `glAreTexturesResident()` seems to be what I want, but it's not defined in iPhone's ES1/ES2 implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
    GLint textureBinding;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &textureBinding);
```

glActiveTexture() returns the active texture unit rather than the binding.

Answer (score 0):

GLES2 provides glActiveTexture(), but the easiest way to determine if you've previously bound a particular texture is to simply keep track of what your most recently-bound texture is, and only call glBindTexture if the texture you want to render is different.

Another thing you might consider is sorting your objects by texture handle, which will further minimize your state changes since you can be sure that you're rendering out all your primitives in contiguous blocks of matching texture state.